# Threads have almost no overhead; processes have considerable overhead. What does it mean?

Tags: multithreading

I came across this statement while reading difference between Thread and Process. Please explain.

Comment: why is it labeled as java? it is also not always true. some OS implement threads almost identically as they implement processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's trying to say that creating a new thread and communicating between threads is reasonably efficient/cheap, whereas creating a new process and communicating between processes is reasonably inefficient/expensive.

It's a bit of a blanket statement though - the costs vary significantly between different operating systems. The statement is "more true" on Windows than on most implementations of Unix (which try to make process creation cheap) and even on Windows it's untrue to say that threads have "almost no overhead". Creating a new thread is still far from a trivial operation.

Comment: Jon, you are right. But when i googled for 'overhead of process' it includes creation as well as number of responsibilities and complexities a particular process has. These parameters are difinitely lesser in case of Thread.

Comment: @Pooja: Well, early versions of Linux implemented threads by creating new processes, more or less - while it would be very odd for creating a thread to be *more* work than creating a process, in some cases the difference can be quite small compared with the overhead of creating *either* of them.

Comment: Ok. Does it mean that those versions of Linux are still used and this statement is not completely true in case of Linux OS?

Comment: Under Linux both process and thread creation is cheap as it is implemented using fork() system call.

Comment: @dimitri thread creation does not use fork(), and fork() is not cheap. Your statement makes no sense.

Comment: @EJP: Ultimately both thread and process creation is based on clone() kernel function. See man clone(2), man fork(2).
Quote from the man page:
Under  Linux, fork() is implemented using copy-on-write pages, so the only penalty that it
       incurs is the time and memory required to duplicate the parent's page tables, and to  cre‐
       ate a unique task structure for the child.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, it's such a broad generalization that it's almost certainly false to at least some degree. I'd read it as saying "threads generally have considerably less overhead than processes."

If we read it that way, it's generally at least somewhat true. In particular, threads (at least as the term is normally used) share a single address space, but processes (again, as the term is normally used) have separate address spaces.

This means that most inter-process communication requires at least one switch between user mode and kernel mode (and often a couple or even more). Quite a bit of inter-thread communication can be done without any switches between user and kernel mode at all. This *does* typically reduce the overhead quite a bit. At the same time, even (for one example) InterlockedIncrement on Windows can an does have a fair amount *more* overhead than a simple (non-interlocked) increment.

Note that I've focused on the communication and synchronization, not on the initial creation of the thread/process in question. While there *are* situations in which it makes sense to consider thread/process creation, it's really *fairly* unusual -- creating either a process *or* a thread typically has enough overhead that you generally want to ensure that it doesn't happen in any tight loops or anything like that if you can avoid it. In particular, creating either one normally requires a switch to kernel mode (again *could* be more than one). The process/thread creation itself is sufficiently complex that there's a noticeable/measurable difference between them, but the switch to kernel mode carries a fair amount of nearly unavoidable overhead.

As to what these mean, it's fairly simple: regardless of whether you use threads or processes, you usually want to pre-create a pool and dispatch tasks to the pool rather than create a new process/thread for each task that arises. The (ostensibly, somewhat) reduced overhead of creating threads doesn't really affect this much.

The place you generally want/need to design differently between the two is in the size of tasks you give, and the granularity and frequency of communication. With a process pool, you want the tasks to be relatively large, and the communication is rare to keep from imposing excessive overhead. With threads, you can use smaller tasks and more frequent communication without worrying nearly as much about the overhead.

Conversely, however, it's easy to exaggerate the difference too. We're typically talking about something like a couple orders of magnitude or so. If you expect (for example) an update once a millisecond from a task dispatched to a thread pool, then you might want to slow that to every 100 milliseconds or so with a process pool, but putting up with minute-long pauses between things like status updates just to reduce overhead isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

A process has its own memory, its own set of FDs, its own memory mapping, its own set of dynamic libraries, and its own set of threads. By contrast, all a thread has is a stack, a PC, and a register set. To simplify considerably.